# Pass scope variable over to new view

Tags: binding, angularjs

I would like to pass a specific variable on to a new view in angularJS.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
$scope.login_username_model = $scope.register_username_model;
$location.path('/confirmation');
```

And in my confirmation view, I'm binding a form field to login_username_model.

However, when I hit the confirmation view, my form is empty. What can I do to fill that variable? Or how could I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If location.path is calling a new route using a different controller, then you cannot pass the variable like this, because the controller creates a new scope.

Your best bet (as in 90% of cases) is to create a service that is injected in both controllers. You can then pass the user info to the service before you change the route / view, and retrieve it back afterwards, since service data is persistent over route changes.

Here's a bare bones set-up: (not by me)

https://gist.github.com/exclsr/3595424

If it is the same controller, there's a setting in your route config that might work:

```
reloadOnSearch: false
```

You can set this per route.

Comment: It is the same controller. However, it seems like the state of the controller is reset after the $location.path() changed. Does angularJS behave that way?

Comment: Yes, the default on location changes is to reload. You can set reloadOnSearch: false in your route config.